# Calendar is not displaying correctly using flatpickr angular

Tags: html, angular

I use angular calendar and when i want display is not displaying correctly,  what i can do for resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you import `flatpicker css` ? Like `import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';`

Comment: Yes i import it in module.

Comment: We can't help you just by looking at picture. If you can replicate the issue on stackblitz then we can help you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=demo%2Ftemplate.html i copy my calendar from there. But Flatpickr not work, my Flatpickr html <td>
        <input
          class="form-control"
          mwlFlatpickr
          [(ngModel)]="event.start"
          (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()"
          [altInput]="true"
          [convertModelValue]="true"
          [enableTime]="true"
          [time24hr]="true"
          dateFormat="Y-m-d H:i"
          altFormat="Y-m-d H:i"
          [inline]="true"
          [value]="event.start"
        />
      </td>